# CKEditor stripping tags and attributes from HTML email

Tags: html, ckeditor, html-email

I have an app which allows a user to import a HTML email and edit the contents before sending it on again. I'm trying to use CKEditor to edit the imported mail but it seems to be stripping out `bgcolor` tags (and probably more)

Here's how I'm initiating
(config [source](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/14-09-29-06-07/full/samples/plugins/htmlwriter/outputhtml.html))

```
var ckconfig = {

    height: 500, 

    extraPlugins: 'htmlwriter',
    contentsCss: 'body {color:#000; background-color#:FFF;}',
    docType: '<!DOCTYPE HTML>',
    allowedContent:
        'h1 h2 h3 p pre[align]; ' +
        'blockquote code kbd samp var del ins cite q b i u strike ul ol li hr table tbody tr td th caption; ' +
        'img[!src,alt,align,width,height]; font[!face]; font[!family]; font[!color]; font[!size]; font{!background-color}; a[!href]; a[!name];' +
        'table[bgcolor|border|width|height|align|cellpadding|cellspacing]; td[bgcolor|border|width|height|align|cellpadding|cellspacing] ',

    coreStyles_bold: { element: 'b' },
    coreStyles_italic: { element: 'i' },
    coreStyles_underline: { element: 'u' },
    coreStyles_strike: { element: 'strike' },

    font_style: {
        element: 'font',
        attributes: { 'face': '#(family)' }
    },

    fontSize_sizes: 'xx-small/1;x-small/2;small/3;medium/4;large/5;x-large/6;xx-large/7',
    fontSize_style: {
        element: 'font',
        attributes: { 'size': '#(size)' }
    },

    colorButton_foreStyle: {
        element: 'font',
        attributes: { 'color': '#(color)' }
    },

    colorButton_backStyle: {
        element: 'font',
        styles: { 'background-color': '#(color)' }
    },

    stylesSet: [
        { name: 'Computer Code', element: 'code' },
        { name: 'Keyboard Phrase', element: 'kbd' },
        { name: 'Sample Text', element: 'samp' },
        { name: 'Variable', element: 'var' },
        { name: 'Deleted Text', element: 'del' },
        { name: 'Inserted Text', element: 'ins' },
        { name: 'Cited Work', element: 'cite' },
        { name: 'Inline Quotation', element: 'q' }
    ]
};

$("#ckeditor").ckeditor(ckconfig);
```

Here's my HTML

```
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="100%" align="center"><!-- Header Row -->
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" bgcolor="#2980b9"><!-- Start Header Table -->
                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" bgcolor="#2980b9">

                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">
                            <font face="arial, sans-serif" color="#ffffff" style="TEXT-ALIGN: center; FONT-STYLE: oblique; DISPLAY: block; FONT-FAMILY: arial, sans-serif; COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-SIZE: 12px">Updates</font>                          
                        </td>
                    </tr>                       
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" valign="top" style="TEXT-ALIGN: center">                             
                            <font face="arial, sans-serif" color="#ffffff" style="FONT-FAMILY: arial, sans-serif; COLOR: #ffffff; FONT-SIZE: 64px" 
        >My<strong>App</strong></font>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here's how it looks in TinyMCE (Which I'm looking to replace)

[image]

And here's the result in CKEditor

[image]

How do stop CKEditor from removing my legacy HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was setting the table[bgcolor] tags in `allowedContent` which wasn't working, but it turns out you can set

```
allowedContent: true,
```

which will just disable ACF (advanced content filtering) entirely.

Comment: Cool, accept this to notify the other people. Also, if you dig around to see which ACF rule was actually causing the problem, it wold make a great addition to this answer. Also, I see you have mixed comma and pipe (|) delimited values in your ACF, are you sure they are both supported? Why not use just one? Also, CKE might be converting your inline bgcolor values to style values, which are not allowed in the old ACF rule - I think that is the most likely culprit. Can you test?

Comment: @Nenotlep I'm not sure how to test that. The HTML created by CKE had no style values so if they were converted they were also stripped. I just spotted pipes vs commas! The last line is my own, the rest comes from the CKE page about HTML4.01 content (linked in question as 'source')

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'ckeditor', {
 height: 500, 
 contentsCss: 'body {color:#000; background-color#:FFF;}',
 docType: '<!DOCTYPE HTML>',
stylesSet: [
    { name: 'Computer Code', element: 'code' },
    { name: 'Keyboard Phrase', element: 'kbd' },
    { name: 'Sample Text', element: 'samp' },
    { name: 'Variable', element: 'var' },
    { name: 'Deleted Text', element: 'del' },
    { name: 'Inserted Text', element: 'ins' },
    { name: 'Cited Work', element: 'cite' },
    { name: 'Inline Quotation', element: 'q' }
],
 allowedContent: {
     'h1 h2 h3 p pre[align] blockquote code kbd samp var del ins cite q b i u strike ul ol li hr table tbody tr td th caption img[!src,alt,align,width,height]':true,

     'span':{
                styles:'*' 
     }, 
     'font':{
         attributes: '!face,!color',
                styles:'*' 
     },                                  
    'table': {
                attributes: 'width,border,cellpadding,cellspacing,align,width,bgcolor',
                styles:'*'                                     
    },
    'tr': {
                attributes: 'height,rowspan'                                 
    },
    'td': {
                attributes: 'width,colspan,align,border,valign',
                styles:'*'                                 
            }
        }

        } );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/whngL8qh/4/

Answer (score 0):

Attributes should be in a comma separated list. You should replace your | (pipes) with commas.